# Functions f that are equal to f' in $L^2(0,\pi)$?

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces, fourier-analysis

The exact question I'm faced with is

> Let f be a continuous real-valued function on $0 < x < \pi$ such that $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$ and $f'\in L^2(0,\pi)$.
> For which functions do we have $\int_0^{\pi}|f(x)|^2dx=\int_0^{\pi}|f'(x)|^2dx$?

I know that convergence in $L^2(0,\pi)$ means that the functions $f$ and $f'$ can still differ on a zero set of points. I still can't think of what type of function is equal to its derivative except for a few points, or on the whole interval for that matter. The only function I can think of is $e^x$, but I was wondering if there is a more general property that ensures the equality above.

Comment: $\int_0^{\pi}|f(x)|^2dx=\int_0^{\pi}|f'(x)|^2dx$ does NOT implies at all that $f = f'$. The functions $f$ and $f'$ can be very different and still have equal integrals.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions

Comment: @jjagmath Yeah that's very true.. I was caught up in thinking about $\int_0^{\pi} |f(x) - f'(x)|^2dx$

Comment: @MartinR In the exercise in my book they give the hint to extend f to an odd function on ($-\pi,\pi$) first, to use the Fourier series of f and f' I presume. We can then make a sine series of f and this series will work equally well on (0,$\pi$). I was wondering, why do they suggest to make an odd extension rather than an even one?

I am also wondering why in the first statement of the theorem on Wikipedia, they have the factor $\pi^2/4L^2$, and why in the Fourier series proof they have the factors $1/\sqrt{\pi}$ in the FS terms. Is this something I have to adjust in my case?

Comment: The second statement in the Wikipedia article is for the boundary condition $y(0) = y(L) = 0$, and then the factor is $L^2/\pi^2$, which in your case is $1$.